# How do I get number of rows that a multi-table delete query will affect in mySQL before deleting?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a rather complex DELETE query that I need to break down into batches, but I can't do that until I can determine how many rows would be deleted before performing the query.  Here is the query that I want to get a count on:

```
DELETE parts, binaries FROM parts LEFT JOIN binaries ON binaries.ID = parts.binaryID LEFT JOIN releasenfo rn ON rn.binaryID = binaries.ID WHERE binaries.procstat IN (4, 6) AND (rn.binaryid IS NULL OR (rn.binaryid IS NOT NULL AND rn.nfo IS NOT NULL))) OR binaries.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR;
```

Here is what I thought might work, but it's not valid:

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM (DELETE parts, binaries FROM parts LEFT JOIN binaries ON binaries.ID = parts.binaryID LEFT JOIN releasenfo rn ON rn.binaryID = binaries.ID WHERE binaries.procstat IN (4, 6) AND (rn.binaryid IS NULL OR (rn.binaryid IS NOT NULL AND rn.nfo IS NOT NULL))) OR binaries.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR) AS countme;
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

To put this into context, I want to use it with the following php pseudo code:

```
$limit = 10000; // Do in batches to give user status            
$totalRows = $db->query("Count query goes here");

while($rowsLeft > 0)
{
    echo "$rowsLeft remaining to be deleted\n";
    $db->query("DELETE ...... LIMIT ".$limit);
    $rowsLeft -= $limit;
}
```

Comment: What do you save by doing that? To figure out the number of rows that will be affected, the query has to be executed. If this was possible, you'd need to execute it twice.

Comment: You will be better off by refactoring this into single table delete statements

Comment: I want to use a loop limiting the query to say 10000 rows on each pass and output status to user as it is performed.

Comment: That seems like a very bad idea to me. Just use the [things already in MySQL](http://www.stillhq.com/mysql/000011.html) to figure out query progress.

Comment: Like what?  I added sample code so you can get an idea what I'm trying to do.  This could take hours to run through completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this:

```
SELECT * FROM parts p 
LEFT JOIN binaries b ON b.ID = p.binaryID AND b.procstat IN (4, 6) 
LEFT JOIN releasenfo rn ON rn.binaryID = b.ID 
WHERE rn.binaryid IS NULL OR (rn.binaryid IS NOT NULL AND rn.nfo IS NOT NULL) OR 
        b.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR;

DELETE p, b FROM parts p 
LEFT JOIN binaries b ON b.ID = p.binaryID AND b.procstat IN (4, 6) 
LEFT JOIN releasenfo rn ON rn.binaryID = b.ID 
WHERE rn.binaryid IS NULL OR (rn.binaryid IS NOT NULL AND rn.nfo IS NOT NULL) OR 
        b.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR;
```

Comment: This gives an error.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') OR binaries.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: extra ")". Seems to work. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parts LEFT JOIN binaries ON binaries.ID = parts.binaryID LEFT JOIN releasenfo rn ON rn.binaryID = binaries.ID WHERE binaries.procstat IN (4, 6) AND (rn.binaryid IS NULL OR (rn.binaryid IS NOT NULL AND rn.nfo IS NOT NULL)) OR binaries.dateadded < '2013-01-04 22:01:17' - INTERVAL 36 HOUR;

Comment: Update your delete query it also have extra ")"

Comment: Remove the extra bracket from ur query